# What is the API name of system permission for analytics?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, ant, permission-sets

What is the API name of the system permission `View Analytics on Communities pages`?

This system permission is not getting retrieved from my org.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SSE!

Have you [Enabled Analytics Features](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/wave_enable_setup/wave_enable_other_cool_stuff) ?

- Go to Salesforce Setup and enter Analytics in the Quick Find /
  Search field.
- Select Getting Started.
- Click Enable Analytics.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_help_setup_basic.htm&type=5